# 2005 chrysler neon clunking noise from front end

Tags: suspension, chrysler

My neon has 125000km.  Recently started clunking especially over speed bumps - replaced the the lower bushes and shock absorbers but still continues.  Related is a Brrrrrr sound on hard acceleration from low speed.  Any one give me ideas as to what to try next?  thanks

Comment: Can you identify even generally where the sound is coming from? eg Left, Right, Centre. This would help - and is the vibration from the same area as the clunk?

Answer (score 1):

Could very well be your motor mounts, if indeed your bushings and shocks needed replacement. The rubber on motor mounts tends to harden and crack and in turn you will get more vibration, movement and noise from the engine. I'd check that before going any further.

Answer (score 0):

Two things I can think of are the mounts, and loose brakes. When you press the brakes the calipers would smash on the wheel. I have seen this on calipers missing one bolt. The strut mounts could be bad/loose and this would also cause the noise. Also, check you rear drive axle unless you know for sure the sound is coming from the front. You mentioned acceleration, how are your engine mounts?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the clunking noise (I'm hearing something similar in my rear), but the other sound you're describing sounds very much like your exhaust is blowing. Probably just a small hole now, I'd work my way from the back of the car and check for serious rust in the exhaust.